# Why is PHP inserting variable name in mysql table database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, forms

I am making a PHP login/register forms.

I made the login, register and configure succesfully and it works, but I really cannot figure why is my code inserting variable names **"email1"** and **"pass1"** into table instead of what I type in?

Please help I reallly looked through it about 50 times and cant see whats wrong.

**Here is my REGISTER form:**

```
    <?php
require ('config.php');

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

//Perform the verification

          $email1 = $_POST['email1'];
          $email2 = $_POST['email2'];
          $pass1 = $_POST['pass1'];
          $pass2 = $_POST['pass2'];

          if($email1 == $email2){
                 if($pass1 == $pass2){
                  //All good carry on

                  $name = mysql_escape_string($_POST['name']);
                  $lname = mysql_escape_string($_POST['lname']);
                  $uname = mysql_escape_string($_POST['uname']);
                  $email1 = mysql_escape_string('email1');
                  $email2 = mysql_escape_string('email2');
                  $pass1 = mysql_escape_string('pass1');
                  $pass2 = mysql_escape_string('pass2');



                   $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `uname` = '$uname'");
                   if (mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0){
                       echo "That user already exists";
                       exit();
                   }


          mysql_query("INSERT INTO `users`(`id`, `name`, `lname`, `uname`, `email`, `pass`) VALUES (NULL, '$name', '$lname', '$uname', '$email1', '$pass1')") or die(mysql_error());

            }else{
                echo "Sorry, your passwords do not match. <br />";
                exit();
            }           
          }else{
              echo "Sorry your emails do not match. <br />";      
          }





}else{

$form = <<<EOT
<form action="register.php" method="POST">
First Name: <input type="text" name="name" /><br />
Last Name: <input type="text" name="lname" /><br />
Username: <input type="text" name="uname" /><br />
Email: <input type="text" name="email1" /><br />
Confirm Email: <input type="text" name="email2" /><br />
Password: <input type="password" name="pass1" /><br />
Confirm password: <input type="password" name="pass2" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Register" name="submit" />
</form>
EOT;

echo $form;

}

?>
```

**Here is my LOGIN form:**

```
<!--KODA ZA ŠUMNIKE-->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" /> 
<?php
 require ('config.php');

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
     $uname = mysql_escape_string($_POST['uname']);
     $pass = mysql_escape_string($_POST['pass']);


 $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `uname` = '$uname' AND `pass` = '$pass'");
 if(mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0){
 echo "You are now logged in.";
 exit();
 }else{
       echo "Wrong username or password combination.";
 }

}else{

$form = <<<EOT
<form action="login.php" method="POST">
Username: <input type="text" name="uname" /><br />
Password: <input type="password" name="pass" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Log in" name="submit" />
</form>
EOT;

echo $form;

}
```

Comment: Are you aware that `mysql_escape_string` was found to be completely broken many years ago? In any event, escaping is the wrong solution; use parameterized queries with PDO or mysqli.

Comment: Why? Because you TOLD php to do it...

Comment: Wow guys you really helped quick!

First I must say I am a complete beginner in this. I only started learning PHP a month ago or less.

Since **ALL of your answers were correct** and very helpfull, I **THANK YOU ALL** very much.

And I didnt know that mysql_escape_string is not in use anymore and I will look into it!

Thanks again for quick and helpfull reply!

P.S.
I would reply sonner but I couldnt because I dont have enough reputation.

Grettings
                     Jan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
              $name = mysql_escape_string($_POST['name']);
              $lname = mysql_escape_string($_POST['lname']);
              $uname = mysql_escape_string($_POST['uname']);
              $email1 = mysql_escape_string($email1);
              $email2 = mysql_escape_string($email2);
              $pass1 = mysql_escape_string($pass1);
              $pass2 = mysql_escape_string($pass2);
```

Should fix it. You are escaping the strings "email1" etc.

also look to moving to mysqli or pdo instead of the old mysql methods

Answer (score 0):

```
              $email1 = mysql_escape_string('email1');
              $email2 = mysql_escape_string('email2');
              $pass1 = mysql_escape_string('pass1');
              $pass2 = mysql_escape_string('pass2');
```

You are not reading the $_POST values here, you're assigning static values.
Since you already read the $_POST Values earlier in the code, I guess you could just delete those four lines.

Answer (score 0):

You must use following code like

```
              $email1 = mysql_escape_string($email1);
              $email2 = mysql_escape_string($email2);
              $pass1 = mysql_escape_string($pass1);
              $pass2 = mysql_escape_string($pass2);
```

Now it will the desired output.

Hope it Helps.